# Checking Request Inspector's current state

Tags: twilio

I'd like to play back credit card numbers for verification purposes; however, when you do this it exposes the redacted CC in the Request Inspector logs. Of course, I can turn these logs off, but Infosec wants more assurances that Request Inspector remains off and that we have steps in place in case it gets turned back on while live calls are arriving or is turned on and forgotten about.

Aside from seeking to have Twilio set it in a permanent state, I've proposed trying to code a status check that would account for either scenario.

That said though, is the Boolean/Toggle for Request Inspector available to be read from the API?

Example lazy code:
IF(Request inspector = 1) say "Please confirm that you wish to pay xx amount"
else if(request inspector = 0) say  "Please confirm that you wish to pay x amount using your credit card 400000000000000"

Basically:
If inspector is on, don't read the CC. 
If it's off, you can read CC

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In reality, you should enable [PCI mode in your voice settings](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings) which is permanent.

As far as I know, you can't read or change the status of the request inspector via the API.

What I might suggest is that for testing you create a separate project within the Twilio console which is responsible for all its own resources. When you run in a test mode you can then use the credentials for this project and log or repeat actions and confirmations as you require. Then, when you run in production mode, you use your production account credentials which are in PCI mode.

Comment: Hey Phil,  I’m actually running PCI mode, but it only redacts the Digits received from the from the previous gather and only if you perform no twiml with the Digits.

Comment: Is there a Non twiml way for me to perform TTS from here?

Comment: So...if I can get a library that will play sounds stored in Twilio Assets (avoiding <play>), I have an out there idea:   Getting each digit from event.Digits using a while loop and a switch that will play an MP3 asset of Polly saying the respective number. Sloppy example: While (currentDig >= lengthCC) {switch (substring(event.digits,currentDig, currentDig+1)) { case ‘1’ currentDig++ audioPlay(assets/one.mp3) case ‘2’.....}}

Comment: Thanks. Happen to know of any plans to allow for Voice body redaction in the same way Im able to redact as necessary in Messages with Enterprise?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Of course, the long term solution to all of this is a `<Pay>` connector that works with your payment provider.